# Semidirect product of C3 by C3

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I got another question regarding semidirect products:

Construct all semidirect products of **C3** ⋊ **C3**.

Comment: What is the automorphism group of $C_3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The automorphism gorup of $C_3$ has only two elements as each automorphism must map a generator to a generator.
Hence no automorphism has order thre, i.e. $C_3$ can act on itself only trivially. This makes the semidirect product a direct product.

Comment: "Hence no automorphism has order thre, i.e. C3 can act on itself only trivially." 

Do you mean order two?

Comment: Explicitly, the automorphism group of $C_3$ consists of the automorphism given by $x\mapsto x^2$ and the identity. These have order 2 and 1, respectively, hnence noe of them has order 3. In other words: An action of $C_3$ on itself is given by a homomorphism $C_3\to \operatorname{Aut}(C_3)\cong C_2$ and there is only the trivial homomorphism.